# Animated PNG (APNG) fallback to gif in unsupported browsers?

Tags: html, animated-gif, apng, image-fallback

So apparently APNGs fall back to the first frame for [unsupported browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=apng)

But is there a way to make it fall back to a gif in unsupported browsers, like we do for webP?

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="image.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="image.jpg" type="image/jpeg">
  <img src="image.jpg">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works! (I thought it was just because the support for `<picture>` and animated png are very similar ([here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=picture) & [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=apng)), but it also works in 'UC Browser for Android', which apparently supports `<picture>` but not APNG)

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="image.png" type="image/apng">
  <source srcset="image.gif" type="image/gif">
  <img src="image.gif">
</picture>
```